# How can i pass 1st page value to 3rd page without session

Tags: php

I have 3 pages. How can I print 1st page value to 3rd page. And my code is following (it just for sample).

**page1.php**

```
<form methord="post" action="page2.php">
username:<input type="text" name="username" >
password:<input type="text" name="password" >
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
$u=$_POST['username'];
$p=$_POST['password'];
?>
<form methord="post" action="page3.php">
username:<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $u?>">
password:<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $p?>">

mobile:<input type="text" name="mobile">
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Now how to print username, password, mobile in **page3.php ?**

Comment: You want to implement this in cookies ?

Comment: yap...ok  Sulthan Allaudeen

Comment: Or use GET variables in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake 1 :**

You `method` name is wrong.

Change this

```
<form methord="post" action="page2.php">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
```

**Implementation**

In the page2

```
<?php
$u=$_POST['username'];
$p=$_POST['password'];
setcookie("u", $u);
setcookie("p", $p);
?>
```

You can get those values in the `page3.php`

```
<?php 
 $u = $_COOKIE["u"];
 $p = $_COOKIE["p"];
?>
The value of Username is <?php echo $u?><br>
The value of Password is <?php echo $p?>
<br>
```

Learn more about [Cookies here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Here is the [eval](https://eval.in/393949) for you

Answer (score 0):

```
username:<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $u;>">
```

Comment: [Code-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo,

replace **methord** to **method**

and simply echo username and other fields on 3rd page like

```
<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>
```